# Select data over a period

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I want to retrieve data from the last 24 hours compared to today's date - 1 day .

The problem is that I don 't have a datetime field in my table but the date separated into 3 parts (day / month / year)

I tried this:

```
select *
from user u
Where DAYOFMONTH (CURDATE () - INTERVAL 1 day) - u.Day <= 1
and MONTH (CURDATE ()) - = 0 u.Month
and YEAR (CURDATE ()) - = 0 u.Year
```

but it does not work if I enter in a new month.

Can you help me please?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the result of this calculation will not be precise. You want to "*retrieve data from the last 24 hours*", but you're not storing time, just date. So you can only retrieve data from *today* or *today and yesterday*:

- When pulling today's records only: a boundary condition can occur when you pull the data at H00:00:01. Since you're not storing time values, you will loose data from yesterday, what most probably means *all data*.
- When pulling today's and yesterday's records: a boundary condition can occur when you pull the data at H23:59:59. Since you're not storing time values, you will pull data from 2 days (- 1 second).

In conclusion, add time values to your table. Preferably one column with `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` data type ([the difference is in range only](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)).

Coming back to your question. Basically, what you want to do is:

```
/*
select * from table
where date >= now - 1 day;
*/
```

How to calculate `now - 1 day`? With [`DATE_SUB()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function:

```
DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

How to make date out of your columns? With [`CONCAT_WS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) and [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) functions:

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', u.Day, u.Month, u.Year, '00', '00', '00'), '%d-%m-%Y-%H-%i-%s')
```

There are zeros in the concatenated string - you can replace them with `u.Hour`, `u.Min`, `u.Sec` as soon as you add these columns to your table. But as I said before, the best performance you will achieve with `DATETIME` column.

Summarizing:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS('-', u.Day, u.Month, u.Year, '00', '00', '00'), '%d-%m-%Y-%H-%i-%s') >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed post, I learned many interesting things and the request works well . Unfortunately, I do not have the right to modify the base so I'll stick to the solution with concatenation

Answer (score 2):

You can format a true date from your fields: `DATE(CONCAT(u.Year, '-', u.Month, '-', u.Day))`; then you can do regular date operations on it (e.g. subtract `INTERVAL 1 DAY`)

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the cast to `DATE`, but it makes it more readable.

Comment: Thx for the tips , i used CONCAT_WS instead for more flexibility

Answer (score 2):

using the iso format you can use convert to get a datetime (tsql)

something like this (not tested)

```
SELECT * from user u 
where DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE()) < convert(datetime, u.Year + u.Month + u.Day )
```

Comment: Thx, unfortunately I am on mysql and not sql server, but I keep the solution aside if I need to work on it in the future

Answer (score 2):

I hope this query should solve it.Hope u.Month,u.Day,u.Year are consitent.

```
select * from user u Where
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(u.Month,'-',u.Day,'-',u.Year), '%m-%d-%Y') = date_add(curdate() , INTERVAL -2 DAY)
```